# ERPNext: Modifying the search pop-up on Purchase Invoice form

Tags: python, development-environment, erpnext, frappe

When I add multiple items under (New Purchase Invoice) as shown below, it gives me the only two items I created so far in order to assign them to the supplier selected.

[image: Desk ScreenShot]

I need to add two more rows in this pop-up (price & quantity) for each item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The Dialog you see is the `LinkSelector` control which is used to select multiple link fields and append them to the child table.

If you open your browser's devtools, you'll notice a `search_widget` API call being made with some parameters like the following:

```
searchfield: name
query: erpnext.controllers.queries.item_query
filters: {"supplier":"_Test Supplier","is_purchase_item":1,"has_variants":0}
doctype: Item
```

You'll have to override the `get_query` call set on `item_code` field of `purchase_invoice.js`. Here's the snippet that queries the current result:

```js
cur_frm.fields_dict['items'].grid.get_field("item_code").get_query = function(doc, cdt, cdn) {
    return {
        query: "erpnext.controllers.queries.item_query",
        filters: {'is_purchase_item': 1}
    }
}
```

Understand how the `item_query` API works and make the appropriate changes to tailor your requirements from there. From a quick search & review of the code, I have a hunch that you'll have to add more fields under the `searchfield` parameter.